# Lebesgue Outer Measure Proof

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am asked to prove:

Prove that $|A|=\lim_{t \to \infty}|A\cap(-t,t)|$ for all $A\subset \mathbb{R}$.

I figured an equivalent statement is  for $R_t=\mathbb{R}\cap\bigg((-\infty,-t]\cup[t,\infty)\bigg)$, show  $|A\cap R_t|\rightarrow 0$.

This follows because $R_t\rightarrow \emptyset$ and $|R_t|\rightarrow 0$.

Since $|A\cap R_t|\le |R_t|$ we get the desired statement. This seems to easy, like I am missing something. Is my proof wrong or do I need to elaborate on some parts? Is there another way to prove this?

Update to Proof:

Given the comments below, I have changed my approach. Consider the set $A_n=A\cap(-n,n)$, where $A_n\subset A_{n+1}$ then by continuity from below of the lebesgue outer measure

$$|\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n|=\lim_{n\to \infty}|A_n|=\lim_{n\to \infty}|A\cap (-n,n)|$$.

Since $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A\cap(-n,n)=A\cap\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} (-n,n)=A.$ We get

$$|A|=\lim_{n\to \infty}|A\cap (-n,n)|$$.

This approach seems to work, but there must be a way to prove this by constructing an open cover and using the definition of the outer measure?

Comment: looks like $|R_t|=\infty$ to me

Comment: @CalvinKhor Doesn't $R_t$ become the null set. Am I wrong in that?

Comment: Yes, so $R_t\downarrow \{\}$, but for each fixed $t<\infty$, $R$ is two infinite length intervals. (Also, I guess you wanted to write $(-\infty,-t]$ instead of $+t$ which would just make $R_t=\mathbb R$)

Comment: A big problem with using $R_t$ is that your proof needs to work also for $A$ with infinite size, e.g. $A=\mathbb R$ or $A=[0,\infty)$. In both cases $|A\cap R_t|\equiv \infty$. so I doubt this reduction is useful. IMO you should write out your definition of the outer measure and go from there